# WinForm Triangle animation

Tags: c#, animation, geometry, move

I am trying to make a triangle move back and forth over an arc, the triangle shoud rotate while moving.

I have made a picture to explain it better:
https://app.box.com/s/mt9p66zlmtkkgkdvtb5h

The math looks right to me, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool turn = false;
    double angle = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Brush solidBlackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black); //En solid svart brush som brukes flere steder
        Pen solidBackPen = new Pen(solidBlackBrush);//En solid svart pen som brukes flere steder

        //Trekant = Norwegian for Triangle, Trekant is a class that draws a polygon shaped as a Triangle.
        Trekant tre = new Trekant();

        e.Graphics.DrawArc(solidBackPen, new Rectangle(new Point(50,50), new Size(100,100)) , 180, 180);

        //X = a + r*Cos(angle) | Y = b + r*Sin(angle)
        double x = (50+(100/2)) + (100/2) * Math.Cos(Trekant.DegreeToRadian(angle));
        double y = (50+(100/2)) - (100/2) * Math.Sin(Trekant.DegreeToRadian(angle));

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform((float)x - 15, (float)y - 40);//Flytter 0 slik at pistolen havner på rett sted
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform((float)-Trekant.RadianToDegree(Trekant.DegreeToRadian(angle-90)));

        tre.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (angle == 0)
        {
            turn = false;
        }
        if (angle == 180)
        {
            turn = true;
        }
        if (turn)
        {
            angle -= 10;
        }
        if (!turn)
        {
            angle += 10;
        }

        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it do currently? it seems strange to me that you are translating before rotating

Comment: The triangle is drawn with respect to 0, so I move 0 to the right spot on the arc and the I rotate the triangle to the correct angle. As of now it looks like the rotation angle is about right, the triangle is not in the right spot.

Comment: Why this: `(50+(100/2)) + (100/2)` and this: `(50+(100/2)) - (100/2)` - those calculations are the same every time. i.e. it's just a constant value. Are you missing a variable? Also a performance tip: declare your pens and brushes just once and reuse them in the class instead of re-creating them every single time.

Comment: (50+(100/2)) is the x and y in the center of the arc. 100/2 is the radius. This two things are the same all the time. Formula is X=a+r*cos(angle), Y=b+r*sin(angle). In this situation a=b as I made the orgin of the arc a sircle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into coding let's first set up the math..

Let say the half ellipse in the picture has a width of `2w` and a height of `h`. And lets assume you want the movement to happen in `n` steps.

Then at each step `s` the rotation angle is `s * 180f/n`. The rotation point's `x` stays at `w` plus whatever offset `ox` the ellipse has,  but will have to move its `y` vertically from offset `oy`, first by `(w-h) * 2f / n` down on each step and then up again by the same amounts..

The Drawing itself moves accordingly.

So you have a `TranslateTransform` for the rotation point, the `RotateTransform`, then another  `TranslateTransform` to place the image, then the `DrawImage` and finally a `ResetTransform`.

I hope that helps. If that doesn't work, please update the question and we'll can get it right, I'm sure..